# how to compare only day part and month part in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date

my requirement is that i have to count occurrence of a certain date and between two months
suppose i have 10-jan-2012 now i have a date range 1-jan-2012 between 1-feb-2013 my requirement is that if i find 10-jan between  1-jan-2012 between 1-feb-2013 irrespective of year i know that 10-jan will come twice between 1-jan-2012 between 1-feb-2013 i am not understanding how to do this.i meanto say that i have to compare only day and month part of the date which will solve my problem

any help will be great hint for me

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it (if I understood the problem correctly):

```
Private Function GetCount(ByVal firstDate As DateTime, ByVal lastDate As DateTime, ByVal toFind As DateTime) As Integer

    Dim count = 0

    For i As Integer = firstDate.Year To lastDate.Year

        Dim current = New Date(i, toFind.Month, toFind.Day)

        If firstDate < current AndAlso current < lastDate Then
            count += 1
        End If

    Next

    Return count

End Function
```